# Copying Editable Excel chart to Word Error 4605

Tags: excel, vba, charts, ms-word

I have a macro that is intended to copy a chart from excel into a word document in the same way as manually copy and pasting using "Keep Source Formatting and Embed Workbook." Below is the code that, to my understanding, should accomplish this.

```
     Set reductionChart = graphWorksheet.ChartObjects("reduction")
     reductionChart.Copy
     masterReport.Paragraphs.Last.Range.PasteAndFormat wdChart
```

graphWorksheet is the worksheet that contains the graphs, masterReport is the word document.

The issue I am having is error 4605 command not available on the PasteAndFormat line. I happened to discover that manually copying the graph then running the line worked without issue. Thinking that maybe right clicking copied in a different way than `.copy` so I record a macro of the action and ended up with:

```
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Reduction").Activate
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
```

Even substituting this in the error still occurs. What is happening here?

After some additional testing I am thinking that possibly when using .copy the chart is sort of only stored within excel and not the clipboard so when paste and format looks for something it see an empty clipboard and has an error, but right clicking copy stores it to the clipboard hence why is available still even after I run `ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy` again.

I've attempted to create new workbook with a single sheet and chart. Also tried using late binding instead on the off chance that did something. This is the full code still giving the same issue

```
Sub test()
    Dim masterWord As Object
    Dim masterReport As Object
    
    Set masterWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set masterReport = masterWord.Documents.Add
    masterWord.Visible = True
    
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).ChartObjects("Chart 1").Copy
    masterReport.Paragraphs.last.Range.PasteAndFormat wdChart
End Sub
```

Comment: For me it works. How did you declare `reductionChart` and `masterReport`

Comment: @Ike ```Dim reductionChart As ChartObject``` and ```Public masterReport As Word.Document``` I've tried it a separate workbook with only the relevant part with the same issue.

Comment: What is in the last paragraph of your word document?

Comment: @Ike The last paragraph is blank. I use ```masterReport.Paragraphs.Add``` then adjust the min and max scale on the graph then run the portion I included. In the newly created sheet. I create a new word document and immediately attempt to copy it with the same result.

Comment: This is strange. When I ran my code again I got the same error :-/ It worked again after I pasted the chart on the same sheet (e.g. `masterReport.Range("B3").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll`) and then pasted it to the word doc. Doesn't make sense ... but maybe that's a hack ...

Comment: It looks like you are using late binding - if you have not made a reference to the Word object library, then wdPaste will be 0 when it should be 16. I can't check what happens with 0:right now but the documentation suggests that this is wdPasteDefault and "is not supported", so that could be the problem.

Comment: @jonsson In the main project I am using early binding. For the test one I used late binding on the off chance it changed something. I do have the reference to Word 16.0 Object Library. 16 and 0 both work. 14 is the one that should work, but isn't. I found a work-around see my answer if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

After much testing this is the best workaround I'm managed to figure out.

```
reductionChart.Chart.ChartArea.Copy
masterReport.Paragraphs.Last.Range.PasteAndFormat wdFormatOriginalFormatting
masterReport.InlineShapes(masterReport.InlineShapes.Count).LinkFormat.BreakLink
```

`wdFormatOriginalFormatting` and `wdPasteDefault` both work and don't seem to make a difference to the outcome as far as I have seen.

This has one issue that I've found which is that on `ActiveDocument.Fields.Update` an information box will popup warning that the linked file is unavailable. This will occur for each unlinked item. I attempted to use `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` but this did not prevent the popup. This may come back to bite me, but I simply removed this line as it was unnecessary for my purposes.